# Convergence of vectors in a normed vector space.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, normed-spaces

I am seeking advice and comments on the following proof and how to improve it, as I have struggled with proofs involving limits.

> Given: Let ($V$,|| ||) be an abstract normed vector. Suppose $V$ contains a sequence of vectors, $\{a_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, which converges to some vector $u$ in $V$.

Claim: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(||a_n||-||u||)=0$

Proof: $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ an integer $N>0$ such that $||a_n-u||<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Then when $n>N, ||a_n-u||<\epsilon$, implying $||a_n||=||u||$. Thus $\{||a_n||-||u||\}=0$.

Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä No my claim is that a sequence $a_n$ which converges to $u \in V$, that the following property holds $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(||a_n||-||u||)=0$ .

Comment: Your proof gets iffy after the first sentence, in both implication and notation.

Comment: @Aweygan Could you give a specific example?

Comment: Well, $\|a_n-u\|<\varepsilon$ implies $\|a_n\|=\|u\|$ is just not true (consider $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})u$).  And it is not clear what you mean by $\{||a_n||-||u||\}=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** You just need to show that 
$$\left|\|x\|-\|y\|\right|\leq\|x-y\|$$
for all $x,y\in V$.

Comment: How about this 
Proof: $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists$ an integer $N>0$ such that $||a_n-u||<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Then when $n>N, ||a_n-u||<\epsilon$. Using the reverse triangle inequality with the above, gives the following $$\epsilon > ||a_n-u|| \geq |||a_n||-||u|||$$. Thus $\{||a_n||-||u||\}=0$.

Comment: @AzJ All but the last sentence is fine. Instead of what is written, say something like "Thus $\{\|a_n\|-\|u\|\}$ converges to $0$".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thank you.